# put \\scaps in RTF for small caps

Tags: c#, richtextbox, rtf

I'm using dynamic RichTextBox control in C# 2.0 and I want to insert "\scaps" in RTF so that if the file is saved programatically and then opened in MS-Word certain text  be seen smallcaps.

Can anyone tell me the code as how to insert the tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can access the rich text directly through the `Rtf` property on the rich text box.